# Telegraf.js does not display some thumbnails in the audio media

Tags: typescript, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf, telegraf.js

By some query, using ytsr I get information about the video (link, thumbnail, etc).

Then, using ytdl-core, I download the audio of this video and return the cropped thumbnail (320x320 - telegram thumbnail standards)

When trying to send an audio message, NOT MEDIA, the thumbnail is shown, all the metadata of the audio recording is correct, such as I specified.

But when I send multiple audios as media, the thumbnail is not displayed, although other metadata, such as the duration or title of the audio, is displayed correctly.

P.S: I tried a variety of methods, made a request for a link to an image, saved to a clipboard, and much more, even used third-party libraries like node-id3 - nothing helps. Media does not display thumbnail.

You can say that this is a bug in telegram or the module that I use ([telegraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/telegraf)), but there is one catch - my bot, when receiving a link to a track in spotify, gets information about it using the [spotify-url-info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spotify-url-info) module, which also returns thumbnail. And now this thumbnail is displayed in the media.

P.S: I saved both thumbnails, they are identical, from file type to size and bit color.

[a function that, by query, returns audio and a thumbnail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TayYm.png)

[Sending media](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJgu9.png)

[Result. The first is just text, he found the track by query. The second is a link to spotify, information about which was returned by the spotify-url-info module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ganA4.png)

[The first photo returned by the ytsr module in my query. I saved it to check if everything is the same with it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPxnr.png)

[Second photo. Telegram displays her thumbnail, although it is the same size as the first one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLK2D.png)

In the media, all audio recordings must have a thumbnail.